# rewriting POST request using async, await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

Is this little bit still valid?  I don't see why it wouldn't be, but I feel like every example I see is a GET request, so I just want to to be sure.

```
const search = async values =>{
const response = await fetch( '/search', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: headers,
     body: values
  })
}
```

coming from this,

```
const search = values => {
  fetch(`/search`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: values
 })
```

I figure if I have that much figured out, then the rest of it is just as simple.

Comment: `async/await` does not care what is the nature of the promise ;). There is no difference between request methods from this point of view.

Comment: That sounds pretty good.  I think this is going to turn into a much differant question.